# How to fit image child inside the container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the output that i'm getting while placing the image as container's child.

[image]

the image is outflowing the container, i needed to fill inside the container, here is my code. i could've use the decoration image inside the container, but i'm using FadeImage widget to display the image, here is the code

```
    Container(
            height: 80,
            width: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: AppTheme.primaryColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
              // image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(image), fit: BoxFit.cover)
            ),
            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
              placeholder: 'assets/images/loading.gif',
              image: imageFromApi,
            ),
          ),
```

how do i fill the image/child widget inside the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can provide the size on `FadeInImage` and setting `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,` should work.

```dart
Container(
  height: 80,
  width: 80,//optinal i think
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(color: AppTheme.primaryColor),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
    // image: DecorationImage(image: NetworkImage(image), fit: BoxFit.cover)
  ),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
    placeholder: 'assets/images/loading.gif',
    image: "imageFromApi",
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
  ),
),
```

Comment: glad to help, you may also like [DecorationImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/DecorationImage-class.html)